# Not able to use unstable library feature 'stdsimd' in Rust even using Nightly

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to compile the following code in the nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu version of rust.

```
    #![cfg_attr(feature = "htm", feature(link_llvm_intrinsics))]
    #![cfg_attr(feature = "nightly", feature(stdsimd))]
    #![cfg_attr(feature = "nightly", feature(rtm_target_feature))]
    #![warn(missing_docs)]


    use core::arch::x86_64 as x86;
    use x86::{
       _xabort, _xbegin, _xend, _xtest, _XABORT_CONFLICT, _XABORT_EXPLICIT, _XABORT_RETRY,
       _XBEGIN_STARTED,
    };


   fn main() {
       let mut x:i64=0;

       _xbegin();
       x+=1;
       _xabort(0);
   }
```

But it is not compiling and giving the following error.
error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'stdsimd'

I am expecting to create hardware transactions using this

I compiled it using the following commands:-

rustup default nightly

cargo run

Following is the entire error code given:-

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGbp2.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Did you activate the `nightly` feature?

Comment: Please post the command that you use to compile this project.

Comment: `rustup default nightly` might or might not change the compiler that is running to the nightly one, any [override](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html) will override the default. Instead of changing the default I suggest a `rust-toolchain.toml` on a per project basis.

Comment: The same issue persists even after making the rust-toolchain.toml file.